# what is the difference between Jenkins Built in LDAP and Jenkins LDAP Plugin

Tags: jenkins, ldap, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I am confused with Jenkins LDAP Plugin and the LDAP that already comes with jenkins without installing any plugin.

Does someone know what is the difference between Jenkins Built in LDAP and Jenkins LDAP Plugin

Ref: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no difference between them.
LDAP feature simply taken out as this plug.

So, I use on my server built-in feature. Work fine.